# Use of Postgres table inheritance

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, database-partitioning

Since Postgres also supports partitioned tables, what is the use of child table.

Suppose there is a table of users which has a column `created_date`. We can store data in 2 ways:

1. We create many child tables of this user table and distribute the data of users on the basis of `created_date` (say, one table for every date, like `user_jan01_21`).
2. We can create a partitioned table with the partitioning key `created_date`

Then what is the difference between these solution?
Basically, I want to know what problem table inheritance can solve that partitioning cannot.

Another doubt I have: if I follow solution 1, and I query the user table without the `ONLY` keyword, will it scan all the child tables?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE where created_date = current_date - 10;
```

Comment: The old inheritance based partitioning is deprecated. If you really need partitioning, use the new declarative partitioning.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)  to see how the query planner works. No reason to keep your doubt, when you can actually see how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the objective is partitioning, as in your example, then there is no advantage in using table inheritance. Declarative partitioning is far superior in ease of use, performance and available features.

Table inheritance has uses that are unrelated to partitioning. Features that partitioning doesn't offer are:

- the child table can have additional columns
- a table can inherit from more than one table

With table inheritance, if you select from the parent table, you will also get all results from the child tables, just as if you had used `UNION ALL` to combine the results.

Comment: …and with table inheritance, foreign key references to the parent table don't work as one might expect